# Why am I getting a 403 error “CSRF token missing” with Django?

Tags: python, django, django-csrf

I’m using [REST Easy](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/rest-easy/) in Firefox to make a POST request to a simple form in Django, but it’s giving me a 403 error “2295 CSRF token missing or incorrect”.

This is my `views.py` (since I’m using the net behind a proxy):

```
from django.shortcuts import render
import urllib2

def home(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        post = request.POST
        if 'passkey' in post:
            if post['passkey'] == '123':
                proxy = urllib2.ProxyHandler({'http': 'http://070.13095070:pujakumari123@10.1.1.19:80'})
                auth = urllib2.HTTPBasicAuthHandler()
                opener = urllib2.build_opener(proxy, auth, urllib2.HTTPHandler)
                urllib2.install_opener(opener)
                j = urllib2.urlopen(post['url'])
                j_obj = json.load(j) 
                return HttpResponse(j_obj)
    else:
        return render(request, 'packyourbag/home_page.html')
```

and my template file:

```html
<html>
    <body>  
        <form id="form" method="post">
            {% csrf_token %}
            url:<input type="text" name="url"/>
            Pass Key:<input type="text" name="passkey"/>
            <button type="submit" name="url_post">
                Post
            </button>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

I’m passing a URL and passkey, and I don't know how to pass a CSRF token (I don’t even know if I have to pass this or not).

Comment: plz also tell what changes i hav to make in my code....when i m just writing @csrf_excempt it is giving error - 'name 'csrf_excempt' is not defined'..help me once again plz..:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can disable the CSRF token requirement by putting `@csrf_exempt` before your view:

First import the decorator at the top of your views.py:

```
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt
```

Then decorate your view like:

```
@csrf_exempt
def home(request):
```

Warning: This will make your view vulnerable to cross site request forgery attacks. See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/csrf/ for details.

Answer (score 0):

It is because you aren't passing the CSRF Token through with `rest-easy`. You can either do as @Selcuk suggested and wrap your view function with `@csrf_exempt` while testing, or you can find the CSRF Token and POST that with `rest-easy`